Matplotlib plot contours of a function with downhill direction?
I am trying to recreate a plot style in matplotlib.
In the plot, the ticks on each contour show the downhill direction of the function. I want to recreate this plot but for the surface -x^3/3+x y^2+x with tick marks showing the downhill direction like in this plot.
How can I achieve this effect in matplotlib?


This example seems to show what you want: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/tickedstroke_demo.html#applying-tickedstroke-to-contour-plots

See also Adding water flow arrows to Matplotlib Contour Plot
